# Program that acts as a printer proxy

Tags: printer

I have a problem here where I have a printer (actually a disc printer), that does not have windows 7 drivers. We have one computer running windows xp that hosts the printer and then we print from another windows xp computer using the standard windows printer sharing. I am wondering if there is a "print driver" program that can take a print job, print to pdf or some other intermediary format, and send it to a print server. The print server would then print to the printer. This way any computer could print without depending on the print driver for that printer.

Comment: And you cant just access the shared printer from your win7 boxes?  Also - many many xp drivers will work just fine on Win7

Comment: No, this printer is ridiculously finicky. This is what we have to work with and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible (I know it is).

Comment: I think what you are talking about is called a RIP server.  You might try looking in that direction.

Comment: Also, providing the make and model of your printer would be helpful.